# Facebook SDK .Net(C#) uploading image offline

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, offline

I am using the v6 C#.Net Facebook SDK (a blog can be found http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx). 
I need to receive access permission to offline_access from users and later on (different session) post images to that user. 
I've also tried uploading images to a certain page (of mine) but couldn't.

I am providing a simple dialog for the user and accept his allow for all the credentials I am asking for "user_about_me,read_stream,user_online_presence,friends_online_presence,offline_access,publish_stream,photo_upload"
Than, in different session (restarting my application), I am creating an access token using the following method:
(using WebRequest as followed:)

```
var url = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials",AppId, AppSecret);
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var myString = (new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
myString = myString.Replace("access_token=", "");
```

However when trying to access a user, that has previously gave an offline_access credentials, using the access token I get exception thrown: 
**(OAuthException) An access token is required to request this resource** 
for a very simple request:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(myString);
var result = fb.Get("/{0}/permissions", userThatGaveCredentials);
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your code to request the access token the second time is not working. There is no reason to do this (and it wont always work anyway). You should just save the access token from when the use logs in the first time.

The error you are receiving is because your myString is null when you pass it into FacebookClient, thus the error that you are not providing an access token.

Also, you should note that offline_access is being deprecated and will be removed in a few weeks so you shouldn't build a new app that uses it anyway.